# Why doesn't Bathurst use the device this way?

Tags: plot-explanation, infinite

The antagonist in *Infinite (2021)* has a device called the dethroner which allows him to download the consciousness of an opponent, thus preventing reincarnation.

But Bathurst's end-goal in the movie is to stop his own reincarnation, so why doesn't he just use the device on himself ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Dethroner would simply capture his soul and imprison him (it is also implied that the captured souls are somewhat conscious), so it would not achieve what he wanted - stopping the cycle completely and to see the god in an afterlife, he would just be stuck in the box somewhere with his thoughts. His ultimate goal seemed to be to see the face of the god or to challenge him. He had lost his faith (and mind) and wanted proof of the divine or just to stop all life as he viewed it as meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

I think he didn't want to take the chance that it didn't work, he would have to 'begin again' if it failed to fully 'kill' him.  At the moment I don't know if the gun makes you forget your previous lives and would have to not be reborn.

There is no way to confirm the device works the way he says it does because the tech would have had to have been a recent invention. Meaning any infinites who have been killed may actually be reborn but without those vital memories, meaning the next time they are reborn to them would be a 'first' from their point if view.

Comment: The end of the film makes it clear that those reborn after having been dethroned (and the flash drives subsequently destroyed) have full memories of their past lives.

Comment: And wasn't his intention to stay dead forever anyway? Why couldn't he shoot himself and trust the infinites to keep his consciousness safe?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given in the movie:
"I must destroy those hard drives and free them all"
If the destruction of a hard drive releases the soul back into the cycle then this would be just like taking some bench time. A hard drive will eventually deteriorate and be destroyed regardless of the used tech. Nothing is permanent. In the grand scheme of things, even his plan may be flawed. Millions of years in the goldie-lock zone. Primordial soup and the creation of life might simply happen on earth again, continuing his torment after millions of years.